# Null checks not inserted for reified type when param is non-nullable

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

**TL;DR** Should functions with reified types take account of type-parameter nullability when generating code?

**Test case**

Consider the following Kotlin code; the only difference between the two methods is whether the type bound is nullable (`Any?`) or not (`Any`).

```
@Test
fun testNonNullableBound() {
    val x: Int = nonNullableBound()
}

@Test
fun testNullableBound() {
    val x: Int = nullableBound()
}

private inline fun <reified T : Any> nonNullableBound(): T {
    return unsafeMethod()
}

private inline fun <reified T : Any?> nullableBound(): T {
    return unsafeMethod()
}
```

where `unsafeMethod` subverts the type system by being defined in Java:

```
public static <T> T unsafeMethod() { return null; }
```

This is Kotlin 1.1.4.

**Expected behaviour**

I'd expect these to behave equivalently - the type is reified, so the actual value of `T` is known to be non-nullable, so a null check ought to be applied inside the function before the `return` statement.

**Observed behaviour**

The two cases fail in different ways:

- `testNonNullableBound` behaves as expected (fails due to a null check on the value returned by `unsafeMethod()`).
- `testNullableBound` doesn't behave as expected - it fails with an NPE when doing the assignment to `x`.

So it appears the insertion of null checks is based on the type bound, rather than the actual type.

**Analysis**

For reference, the relevant bytecode is as follows.  Note the null check added in `testNonNullableBound`.

***testNonNullableBound***

```
public final testNonNullableBound()V
  @Lorg/junit/Test;()
   [...]
   L1
    LINENUMBER 28 L1
    INVOKESTATIC JavaStuff.unsafeMethod ()Ljava/lang/Object;
    DUP
    LDC "unsafeMethod()"
    INVOKESTATIC kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V
   [...]
```

***testNullableBound***

```
public final testNullableBound()V
  @Lorg/junit/Test;()
   [...]
   L1
    LINENUMBER 27 L1
    INVOKESTATIC JavaStuff.unsafeMethod ()Ljava/lang/Object;
   [...]
```

Comment: `null check ought to be applied inside the function before the return statement.`
Why you are making that assumption ?
You call first `unsafeMethod` and then check nullability on it,

Comment: @crgarridos - Because that's what happens in a non-generic scenario (and I was assuming reified types would be equivalent to that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So it appears the insertion of null checks is based on the type bound, rather than the actual type.

Exactly right, this is how it is supposed to work!

A JVM function cannot have different byte code depending on the actual generic type, so the same implementation has to satisfy all possible outcomes.

Inlining doesn't affect this case because it follows the same rules as normal functions. It was designed in this way so that the developer is less surprised.

Comment: If it's the case that inline functions should have the same semantics as non-inline functions, then this line of reasoning makes total sense.  (Though FWIW, this particular developed *was* surprised by the behaviour ;)

Comment: For completeness, do you know of any documentation/specs/etc. that state this?  (i.e. that inline functions should behave semantically like normal functions.)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth since it is not stated otherwise, I conclude that the rules for inlined generics are the same as everywhere else

Comment: There is this spec, but I don't think it mentions this problem https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/spec-docs/reified-type-parameters.md

Comment: Frankly, I know this because the compiler works this way: firstly all types are checked and resolved, secondly byte code of inline functions is copied on code generation and optimizations are performed. This process insures that the semantics of inline generics does not change.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem isn't if the function is inlined or not.**

From Kotlin's [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types):

> Any reference in Java may be null, which makes Kotlin's requirements of strict null-safety impractical for objects coming from Java. Types of Java declarations are treated specially in Kotlin and called platform types. Null-checks are relaxed for such types, so that safety guarantees for them are the same as in Java

Using a `@Nullable` annotation, in java side, you can enforce kotlin to check if the type can either be null or not (using `@NotNull`)

```
@Nullable
public static <T> T unsafeMethod() { return null; }
```

Comment: That quote makes sense in isolation.  However my misunderstanding/confusion was about the *runtime* checks the compiler inserts, not static checks.